# The principal argument of a complex number in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

**If z=r(cos θ + isin θ), where r>0 and 0< θ < 1/2π, find in terms of r and θ the modulus and principal argument of....**

*a) -z*

> I started off by: -z=-r(cos θ + isin θ)  ---> = r(-cos θ - isin θ) = r(-cos(-θ) + isin (-θ)).
>
> a= -rcos -θ    b= rsin -θ
>
> √(-rcos(-θ))^2 + (rsin (-θ))^2) = r
>
> I have no idea how to continue from this. I know the formula for the argument is --> tan θ = b/a
>
> Plugging in the values I have would result in tan θ = -tan -θ
>
> The answer is supposed to be Mod= r   Arg= θ - π

Answer (score 1):

$$-z = z(-1) = re^{i\theta}e^{i\pi} = re^{i(\theta+\pi)}$$
Hence, Modulus is $r$

Now for principal argument, the angle by definition must lie in $(-\pi, \pi]$. Therefore, we need to translate $\pi + \theta $ to this interval. Since $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi/2$, we use
$$\tan(\theta) = \tan(\theta - 2\pi)$$
Giving us our primary argument as $\theta - \pi$

Comment: How does -1 =  ??

Comment: $e^{i\pi} = \cos{\pi} + i\sin{\pi} = -1 + 0 = -1$